# Not being able to use turicreate

Tags: python, xcode, python-2.7, terminal, turi-create

I am trying to use `turicreate`. I installed it on my device (`sudo python2.7 -m pip install turicreate`) And when I ran my code (in terminal on Mac), I got a long error message. I believe that the significant part is as follows:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/cython/cy_unity.so, 2): Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN`

Here is the integrity of it for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turicreate as turi
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from turicreate.data_structures.sgraph import Vertex, Edge
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import sframe
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/sframe.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..connect import main as glconnect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/connect/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..cython.cy_unity import UnityGlobalProxy
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/cython/cy_unity.so, 2): Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/cython/../libunity_shared.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/cython/../libunity_shared.dylib
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Here's a [search for this error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=importerror+Symbol+not+found%3A+_syslog%24DARWIN_EXTSN&t=lm&ia=qa).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31106958/472495), and that has another suggested link as well.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer , thank you, I will keep that in min going forward

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. Your profile card is your signature. We also try to avoid greetings, regards, thanks, advance thanks, hope-that-you-can-helps, requests for urgency, apologies for English, and other material that is not germane to the question.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with the beta for 5.0.  Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This article provides a detailed explanation of setting up Python environment for popular ML packages on Mac - [Machine Learning Compass](https://medium.com/@maxim.volgin/machine-learning-compass-fcee3d9ac3b3)